# Why standard does not provide specialization for hashing c strings with content examination

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am reading about hashing and I found following statement in [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> There is no specialization for C strings. `std::hash<const char*>` produces a hash of the value of the pointer (the memory address), it does not examine the contents of any character array.

Why there is no mechanism that hashes C strings that examine their content?

I was browsing code for `std::string_view` and it seems like it would come handy to cover both: `std::string` and `std::string_view`.

**Edit**

Thanks for the comments. I think I wasn’t very clear. I should ask why there is no functionality to hash c strings with giving its length as an argument? `hash(const char* data, size_t size)` would handle nul, and not nul terminated c strings.

Comment: `const char*` not necessary point to nul-terminated string...

Comment: @Jarod42 Somehow that didn't prevent providing `operator<<(ostream&, const char*)` overload.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::hash<std::string>{}(foo)` (where `foo` is a `char const *`) ?

Comment: Why copy/allocate just to hash?

Comment: I see... so starting from C++17 `std::hash<std::string_view>{}(foo)` should be OK but not in C++11/C++14

Comment: Yes. Also I am locked down to gcc-4.8 so I can forget about SSO. Seems like such a basic thing to me, hash some const char* with certain length.

Comment: @PiotrBarejko Have you thought about how your proposed `hash(const char* data, size_t size)` would be used by containers that are designed to call `hash(Key k)` (i.e. a unary hash function)?

Comment: @JaMiT I wasn't implying to put it as a specialization of `std::hash`. I noticed, that there are many useful operations in `std::char_traits` that could be(or maybe already are) shared between `std::string` and `std::string_view`, but for some reason hashing is not one of them. I wonder why. For now, I just use `std::_Hash_impl::hash`. It exactly does what I want, a the same time I am aware I am touching implementation details...

Comment: @PiotrBarejko *"I wasn't implying to put it as a specialization of std::hash."* -- correct, it was not an implication. You directly asked about specializations of `std::hash`.

Comment: By the way: *"there are many useful operations in `std::char_traits` that could be(or maybe already are) shared between `std::string` and `std::string_view`, but for some reason hashing is not one of them. I wonder why."* -- This is a different question than the one you asked. You asked why standard hasing does not handle C-style strings, whereas this other question amounts to asking why hashing is not considered part of the named requirement [CharTraits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CharTraits). The answers are independent of each other. Please stick to one question at a time.

Comment: A third question, which might be your real question, is how you can calculate a hash of a C-style string using standard tools, without touching implementation details. This is the easiest of the three questions to answer, so if it is your real question, it is a shame that you hid it as an implication in a comment (you should instead ask it in a new question, if this is indeed something you are interested in and if you cannot find it already answered here).

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks a lot. Next time I will be more precise and ask one question at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A specialization is not possible because "C-strings" are just pointers with the implication that they're null-terminated. A `const char *` could just as well be a pointer to some raw byte data, not necessarily a C-string. You simply can't assume that all `const char *` are null-terminated.

Your suggestion with `std::string_view` is not a good idea if you are using `std::string`, because when the associated `std::string` gets destroyed, the `std::string_view` becomes invalid.

Your suggestion would only work if you can guarantee that the associated C-string or `std::string` stays alive as long as the `std::string_view` is stored inside the map.

> It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the resulting string view does not outlive the string.

(see [`std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::operator basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view))

Comment: These considerations didn't prevent the standard library from providing `operator<<(ostream&, const char*)` overload that assumes a nul-terminated string.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The operator overload is for `const void *`, not specifically for `const char *`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt. I suppose that this overload is an inconsistency in the standard library. But if it wasn't for this overload, you couldn't print string literals via `<<`, so it's important to have it here.

Comment: There is too [an overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) specifically for `const char*`, that prints the actual string (presumed nul-terminated) the pointer points to. In light of this, I don't quite grasp the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh ok, I didn't see that there were more overloads defined in the header itself. It is comparing apples and oranges though. When printing via streams, it does make sense to assume `const char *` is a string-literal, for `std::hash` it doesn't.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik on a side note, hash maps aren't good associative containers for strings anyways. Hashing long strings can be quite expensive, more so than comparing just the first couple of characters lexicographically inside a `std::map`. And what's even better is a trie or a radix tree.